# I cant insert into sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[IMDB database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY15F.png)
[Image to database structure FletNix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgTs.png)

```
INSERT INTO FletNix_2.dbo.Movie_Cast
    SELECT cast(Pid AS int) AS person_id,
    cast(Mid AS int) AS movie_id,
    LEFT(Role, 255) AS role
    FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_Cast

INSERT INTO FletNix_2.dbo.Movie_Directors
    SELECT cast(Did AS int) AS person_id,
    cast(Mid AS int) AS movie_id
    FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_Movie_Directors
```

ERROR MASSAGE:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 71 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'pk_moviecast'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Movie_Cast'. The duplicate key value is ((Unknown)).
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 77 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_directors_Person". The conflict
>   occurred in database "FletNix_2", table "dbo.Person", column
>   'person_id'.

I know i need to use distinct, but when i do

```
INSERT INTO FletNix_2.dbo.Movie_Cast
    SELECT cast(Pid AS int) AS person_id,
    cast(Mid AS int) AS movie_id,
    distinct LEFT(Role, 255) AS role
    FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_Cast
```

it gives an error:
incorrect syntax near distinct

When i put distinct after SELECT i still get a error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_moviecast'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Movie_Cast'. The duplicate key value is
>   ((Unknown))

AND

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_directors_Person". The conflict occurred in database "FletNix_2",
>   table "dbo.Person", column 'person_id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distinct should be after `select`

```
    INSERT INTO FletNix_2.dbo.Movie_Cast
    SELECT distinct cast(Pid AS int) AS person_id,
    cast(Mid AS int) AS movie_id,
    LEFT(Role, 255) AS role
    FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_Cast
```

as you role column is primary so it has not to be duplicated so i used row_number() for generation unique number

```
     select 
    cast(Pid AS int) AS person_id,
    cast(Mid AS int) AS movie_id,        
    row_number()over( order by (select null)) as role
    FROM MYIMDB.dbo.Imported_Cast
```

Comment: i edited my question, because it still give the error

Comment: @legitcoding what is your primary key column? is that persion_id?

Comment: I added the database structure, i hope you can help!

Comment: @legitcoding in you Movie_Cast table role is primary key am i right?

Comment: Yet role i the primary key there

Comment: @legitcoding where is your Imported_Cast table?

Comment: It's in another Database and my assignment is to insert from IMDB database to my FletNix_2 database, i will add the database structure of that databast aswel

Comment: @legitcoding you have to use unique role so you need to generate unique number  i used row_number for that

Comment: Also the second INSERT is also giving me the error that is in the last quote block from this post

Comment: I get: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_movieCast_person". The conflict occurred in database "FletNix_2", table "dbo.Person", column 'person_id'.                                                                                          
And: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_directors_Person". The conflict occurred in database "FletNix_2", table "dbo.Person", column 'person_id'.

Comment: All of them are forign keys

Comment: @legitcoding then drop primary key constraint

Comment: for move id and person id?

Comment: @legitcoding those colum can be duplicated but they foreign key remove for them if moveid and persion id is two of that then remove 2